# How to make git check every file's contents even though stat info may not have changed?

Tags: git

I use git to distribute code to an embedded system. Sometimes files get corrupted without changing the mtime, and I want to re-check everything out. Git normally doesn't bother checking the sha of files where the stat info hasn't changed. How can I make it check?

I've tried with

```
git -c core.ignorestat=yes reset --hard
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `core.trustctime` to `false`:

> core.trustctime
>
> > If false, the ctime differences between the index and the working copy are ignored; useful when the inode change time is regularly modified by something outside Git (file system crawlers and some backup systems). See git-update-index(1). True by default.

(I haven't tried this, but it looks like it might do the trick.)

Comment: Setting core.trustctime to false makes git ignore spurious changes to ctime, which apparently happens on some file systems. I need the opposite behavior: re-computing the file hash even when mtime hasn't changed.